# Busca PHP/MySQL (mostrar apenas resultado exatamente igual ao digitado)

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

php recolhe os dados de inputs usando método POST. Ele está conectado direitinho, tá pesquisando, mas **ao digitar o UF e Município ele não me mostra apenas exatamente o que digitei, mas também os relacionados**! tipo digitei SP - São Paulo, ele não me mostra só isso ele mostra SP - São Carlos, SP- São Fulano, SP - São Siclano etc. enfim, mostra todos de tem s, ou ã e eu quero que mostre SOMENTE EXATAMENTE O QUE DIGITEI. Se Alguém souber e puder ajudar fico muito grata. Segue meu cógido:

```
<?php

include ('conectar.php');

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$database);
 if (!$connection) { echo ("Erro ao conectar"); }

$opcao = $_POST["opcao"];
if($opcao == "2"){
    $sg_uf = '"%'. $_POST["txtsg_uf"] .'%"';
    $nm_municipio = '"%'. $_POST["txtnm_municipio"] .'%"';
    $nm_candidato = '"%'. $_POST["txtnm_candidato"] .'%"';
    $dt_ano = '"%'. $_POST["txtdt_ano"] .'%"';

$query = "SELECT * FROM resultado "
. "WHERE sg_uf LIKE ".$sg_uf." OR nm_municipio LIKE ".$nm_municipio." OR nm_candidato LIKE ".$nm_candidato." OR dt_ano LIKE ".$dt_ano."";

    $result =  mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!$result) {
      die("Query inv&aacute;lida na sele&ccedil;&atilde;o dos dados");
    }

    while ($dados=  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        if ($result > 0){
            echo "Op&ccedil;&atilde;o de Busca Avan&ccedil;ada/Elei&ccedil;&otilde;es Municipais: <br />";
            echo "Encontramos!<br/ >";
            echo "UF do Estado: $dados[sg_uf]<br />"; 
            echo "Nome do Munic&iacute;pio: $dados[nm_municipio]<br />"; 
            echo "Nome do Candidato: $dados[nm_candidato]<br />"; 
            echo "Ano da Elei&ccedil;&atilde;o: $dados[dt_ano]<br />"; 
            echo "<hr>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Desculpe, nada foi encontrado.";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: use `AND` se quer resultados com todas as condições. `OR` vai te retornar coisas que tem a condição A, OU a condição B, ou a condição C. Outra coisa, `LIKE` não é pra buscas exatas. Pra buscas exatas basta o `=`

Comment: @Bacco Fiz assim mas não apareceu nada `$query = "SELECT * FROM resultado_votacao_candidato_zona_eleicaomunicipal "
. "WHERE sg_uf = ".$sg_uf." AND nm_municipio = ".$nm_municipio." AND nm_candidato = ".$nm_candidato." AND dt_ano = ".$dt_ano."";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, agradeço a todos que me ajudaram, principalmente ao Bacco, muito obrigada! A partir do que me passaram por aqui cheguei ao seguinte resultado:

```
<?php
include ('conectar.php');


$sg_uf = '"%'. $_POST["txtsg_uf"] .'%"';
$nm_municipio = '"%'. $_POST["txtnm_municipio"] .'%"';
$nm_candidato = '"%'. $_POST["txtnm_candidato"] .'%"';
$dt_ano = '"%'. $_POST["txtdt_ano"] .'%"';

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$database);
 if (!$connection) {
 echo ("Servidor temporariamente fora de servi?o"); 
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM resultado "
. "WHERE sg_uf LIKE ".$sg_uf." and  nm_municipio LIKE ".$nm_municipio." and  nm_candidato LIKE ".$nm_candidato." and  dt_ano LIKE ".$dt_ano."";
$result =  mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Query invalida");
}

while ($dados=  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

if ($result > 0){

echo " Encontramos!<br />";

    echo "UF do Estado: $dados[sg_uf]<br />"; 
    echo "Nome do Municipio: $dados[nm_municipio]<br />"; 
    echo "Nome do Candidato: $dados[nm_candidato]<br />";
    echo "Ano das Eleicoes: $dados[dt_ano]<br />";  
    echo "<hr>";

}
else {
    echo "Desculpe, nada foi encontrado";
}
}
?>
```

É isso ai tá funcionando direitinho, só me mostra exatamente o que digitei.

Answer (score 1):

Sarah, tente mudar a sua SQL para a seguinte forma:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM resultado "
. "WHERE sg_uf LIKE '%".$sg_uf."' OR nm_municipio LIKE '%".$nm_municipio." OR      nm_candidato LIKE ".$nm_candidato." OR dt_ano LIKE ".$dt_ano."";
```

O que eu fiz foi colocar uma aspa simples após o LIKE com o curinga %.

Comment: Diego, feito conforme sugerido.

Comment: Fiz exatamente como vc colocou mas deu query inválida ai modifiquei assim: `$query = "SELECT * FROM resultado_votacao_candidato_zona_eleicaomunicipal "
. "WHERE sg_uf LIKE '%".$sg_uf."' OR nm_municipio LIKE '%".$nm_municipio."' OR nm_candidato LIKE '%".$nm_candidato."' OR dt_ano LIKE '%".$dt_ano."'";` mas não deu certo, não mostrou nada